# Error Excel data being pasted is not the same size as the selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, paste

How can the following text be pasted in a 3*3 grid in Excel? When I try to do so, I get an error message stating that the data being pasted is not the same size as the selection.

12000   0   10
24524   0   10
24435   0   10

Comment: when pasting just choose the upper left corner cell of the target range.  Also, if the cells are merged differently than the source this may cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot paste a table like this from a TXT or DOC file into Excel.  Excel will import it as text and try to paste each line into a single cell or into any cells that you highlight.  Depending on what cells you highlight in destination spreadsheet you may provoke different error messages.  Excel will respect the linefeeds.

To successfully import a table like this you should edit the source file and insert tabs  instead of spaces between each group of figures, e.g.

12000#0#10

24524#0#10

24435#0#10

(Showing the tab character using the hash sign (#) is the only way to illustrate what I mean because inserting a real tab from the keyboard kicks me out of this message box!)

Copying this tab separated table into the top left hand cell of the desired location on the spreadsheet will produce the 3x3 grid you seek.

For info. this technique can be used to transfer tables with blank cells in them or tables of unequal numbers, e.g.

12000##0#10#5#1

24524#0##10##7

24435#0#10#6

will produce the 3x6 grid shown in the this link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVAdq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have your text in the clipboard, click ONCE on the upper left cell where you want to copy it to. (If you click twice and the cell is showing a blinking cursor, press ESC)
2. Now paste the text. It should fill three cells in the leftmost row with the text data like this:

|  | *A* | *B* | *C* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *1* | 12000 0 10 |  |  |
| *2* | 24524 0 10 |  |  |
| *3* | 24435 0 10 |  |  |
| *4* |  |  |  |

1. Now use excel text-conversion-wizard to convert to your need. You should find it under Data|Text-to-columns (not sure how it is called in English or your language). With it, you can convert data stored in the leftmost cells by separating it. You may separate it by fixed width or by a separator, both works in your example. This will be the result:

|  | *A* | *B* | *C* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *1* | 12000 | 0 | 10 |
| *2* | 24524 | 0 | 10 |
| *3* | 24435 | 0 | 10 |
| *4* |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. paste into one column
2. Select that column
3. Go to Data > Text to Columns
4. Click the "Delimited" buttom
5. Click next
6. Under "Delimiters" check the "space" box
7. click "finish"